# adonis.js Cannot read property 'render' of undefined" [closed]

Tags: javascript, adonisjs

empecé a crear una pagina web y cuando llamo al método render de view para devolver HTML me sale el siguiente error

> // 20211116181206 // http://127.0.0.1:3333/
>
> {   "message": "Cannot read property 'render' of undefined",
> "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined\n
> at Object.handler
> (C:\Proyectos\hello-world\start\routes.ts:24:27)\n    at
> Object.PreCompiler.runRouteHandler [as fn]
> (C:\Proyectos\hello-world\node_modules\@adonisjs\http-server\build\src\Server\PreCompiler\index.js:44:50)\n
> at Runnable.invoke
> (C:\Proyectos\hello-world\node_modules\co-compose\build\src\Runnable.js:55:48)\n
> at BodyParserMiddleware.handle
> (C:\Proyectos\hello-world\node_modules\@adonisjs\bodyparser\build\src\BodyParser\index.js:104:20)\n
> at Injector.callAsync
> (C:\Proyectos\hello-world\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\Injector.js:124:30)\n
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"

así esta mi código :

```
Route.get('/', async ({ view }) => {
  const html = await view.render('login', {
    greeting: 'Hello',
  })
  return html
})
```

que viene de la documentación, la vista login la genere con node ace make:view login

Comment: Si importas View en tu archivo, `import View from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/View'`, View con mayus Inicial, que es como lo exporta la Liberia.

Comment: copie la line directamente de la documentación y no compila en la consola me sale : IocLookupException: E_IOC_LOOKUP_FAILED: Cannot resolve "Adonis/Core/View" namespace from the IoC Container

Comment: Probaste ejecutar el comando `npm run build` antes del `npm run start` ?

Answer (score 0):

tuve que volver a ejecutar el comando para inicializar el proyecto y todo funciono bien, talvez no se había instalado correctamente el modulo npm i @adonisjs/view